# synergyでマウスをシェアできるclientの最大数を増やすことは可能ですか？

Tags: ubuntu

現在、synergy(無料版)を使い、serverーclient間（どちらのOSもubuntu 16.04）でマウスとキーボードのシェアを行っています。

10台のclientと1台のserverをセットアップして、すべてのserver-client間で動作確認はできました。

ここで質問です。
このシェアできる最大の数を増やすことは可能でしょうか?。

すこし分かりにくいのですが、synergy configurationでグラフィカルに設定できる最大の数は１５だと認識しています。(添付したイメージでボックスの数が１５ですので、そのように考えています。)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
この最大の数を増やすことは可能でしょうか?

もしどなたかご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: 会社の [ヘルプ](https://symless.com/help) あるいは [フォーラム](https://symless.com/forums/) で質問するか、ソースコード [symless/synergy-core](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core) または [synergy-stable-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy-stable-builds/) を調べてみるのが早いのでは？

Comment: ありがとございます！ソースコードなどは知りませんでしたので、一度自分で調べてみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。